# How to use ipv6 flow label

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, ipv6

I was going through ipv6, and came across flow label.
my question is.
How to use IPv6 Flow Label?
Is there any config which we need to enable/configure to enable flow label? 
Is there a way to configure a default for the Flow Label field in the IPv6 header?
Is there a configurable policy how to handle the Flow Label field in received packets?

Comment: The purpose of the Flow Label is to let the intermediate devices, e.g. routers, make sure that a single flow uses the same path when given a choice of paths. The network stack should automatically deal with the Flow Label for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check sysctl's; https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt

```
flowlabel_consistency - BOOLEAN
    Protect the consistency (and unicity) of flow label.
    You have to disable it to use IPV6_FL_F_REFLECT flag on the
    flow label manager.
    TRUE: enabled
    FALSE: disabled
    Default: TRUE

auto_flowlabels - INTEGER
    Automatically generate flow labels based on a flow hash of the
    packet. This allows intermediate devices, such as routers, to
    identify packet flows for mechanisms like Equal Cost Multipath
    Routing (see RFC 6438).
    0: automatic flow labels are completely disabled
    1: automatic flow labels are enabled by default, they can be
       disabled on a per socket basis using the IPV6_AUTOFLOWLABEL
       socket option
    2: automatic flow labels are allowed, they may be enabled on a
       per socket basis using the IPV6_AUTOFLOWLABEL socket option
    3: automatic flow labels are enabled and enforced, they cannot
       be disabled by the socket option
    Default: 1

flowlabel_state_ranges - BOOLEAN
    Split the flow label number space into two ranges. 0-0x7FFFF is
    reserved for the IPv6 flow manager facility, 0x80000-0xFFFFF
    is reserved for stateless flow labels as described in RFC6437.
    TRUE: enabled
    FALSE: disabled
    Default: true

flowlabel_reflect - INTEGER
    Control flow label reflection. Needed for Path MTU
    Discovery to work with Equal Cost Multipath Routing in anycast
    environments. See RFC 7690 and:
    https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-wang-6man-flow-label-reflection-01

    This is a bitmask.
    1: enabled for established flows

    Note that this prevents automatic flowlabel changes, as done
    in "tcp: change IPv6 flow-label upon receiving spurious retransmission"
    and "tcp: Change txhash on every SYN and RTO retransmit"

    2: enabled for TCP RESET packets (no active listener)
    If set, a RST packet sent in response to a SYN packet on a closed
    port will reflect the incoming flow label.

    4: enabled for ICMPv6 echo reply messages.

    Default: 0
```